# collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c, windows-7, opengl-3, glfw

I am programming since a few days and I simply want to open a window with opengl. I got glew and glfw, I linked the library of glew and the headers of both but when I compile I get an error. I've got windows7. I use def c++.

This is the code:

```
#define GLEW_NO_GLU
#define GLFW_NO_GLU

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


int main() {
GLFWwindow* window1 = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "window1", NULL, NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window1);
return 0;
}
```

And this are the errors:

```
C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL\main.o   In function `main':
C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL\main.cpp undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL\main.cpp undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the compiler log or however it is called:

```
Compiler: TDM-GCC 4.7.1 32-bit Release
Building Makefile"C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL\Makefile.win"
Führe  make... aus
mingw32-make.exe -f "C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -D__DEBUG__ main.o -o Projekt2.exe -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc glew-1.10.0/lib/Release/Win32/glew32.lib -m32 -g3

main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Programmieren\Code\c++_Projekt2_OpenGL/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

mingw32-make.exe: *** [Projekt2.exe] Error 1

Compilation failed after 0,14 seconds with errors
```

Comment: Are you linking the libraries correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log messages you posted, it seems that you haven't configured your Dev-C++ project properly to link against `glfw`:

```
g++.exe -D__DEBUG__ main.o -o Projekt2.exe -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc glew-1.10.0/lib/Release/Win32/glew32.lib -m32 -g3
```

The `glfw` library is missing, that is why you're getting an undefined reference to its functions. You should set up it as you did with `glew32`.

Also, the link to [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), provided in the comments to your question, is worth the read.

Comment: Glew 3.0 is using CMake not the normal libraries. I don't really know how to use this could you help me? How can I link it?

Comment: http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_source

Comment: I suppose you can use directly the binaries from the glflw website? you don't need to compile it. Maybe this can help: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/636326-setting-up-glfw-for-mingw-codeblocks/